# Spring custom SQL error code translator not catching connection exception

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

Using Spring JdbcTemplate with HikariCP and JTDS to connect to MS SQL Server database in legacy code that I'm maintaining. I'm trying to handle the case where the application has started and later for whatever reason the database becomes unavailable and a connection exception is thrown.

I already have a custom SQL error code translator (below) that captures many other exceptions thrown by jdbcTemplate. But the connection refused exception is not being caught even though it is being encapsulated as a java.sql.SQLException (see the stack trace).

Why is the translator not capturing this exception?

```
public class CustomSqlErrorCodeTranslator extends 
                    SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator   {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    @Override
    protected DataAccessException customTranslate
    (String task, String sql, SQLException sqlException) {
        /* 
         * We want to capture all codes.      
         */
            StringBuilder logMsg = new StringBuilder("*********************SQL Exception:");
            logMsg.append(", errorCode: " + sqlException.getErrorCode())
                  .append(", message: " + sqlException.getMessage())
                  ;
            log.error(logMsg.toString());


        return null;
    }



}
```

```
public class Dao {

    //HikariDataSource dataSource;
    DataSource dataSource;

    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private boolean connected = false;
    private CustomSqlErrorCodeTranslator exceptionHandler;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    //this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);


        try {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
            exceptionHandler = new CustomSqlErrorCodeTranslator();
            this.jdbcTemplate.setExceptionTranslator(exceptionHandler);
            connected = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
                log.error("******Cannot connect to database.***************************");
                log.debug(e.getMessage());


            }

        }
    }

}
```

```
16:59:33,542 [main] WARN  PoolBase  - springHikariCP - Connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection@42206bce failed alive test with exception I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
16:59:33,542 [Hikari connection closer (pool springHikariCP)] DEBUG PoolBase  - springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection@42206bce: (connection evicted or dead)
16:59:34,530 [main] DEBUG HikariPool  - Timeout failure pool springHikariCP stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:59:34,544 [Hikari connection adder (pool springHikariCP)] DEBUG HikariPool  - springHikariCP - Cannot acquire connection from data source
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:65)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:567)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:560)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
    ... 13 more
16:59:35,746 [Hikari connection adder (pool springHikariCP)] DEBUG HikariPool  - springHikariCP - Cannot acquire connection from data source
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:65)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:567)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:560)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
    ... 13 more
16:59:37,010 [Hikari connection adder (pool springHikariCP)] DEBUG HikariPool  - springHikariCP - Cannot acquire connection from data source
```

Sorry that it took me this long to realize I needed to add to the stack trace.

Here is the stack trace when I stop the database. Now it is clear that JDBC Template is involved. And if JdbcTemplate is involved it seems to me the custom exception handler should pick it up. Has anyone else had any experience capturing the database connection exception using the custom error code translator?

```
5:06:05,076 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] DEBUG HikariPool  - Timeout failure   pool HikariPool-0 stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=2)
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 10000ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937)
    at com.pevco.persist.resources.AvailabilityDaoImpl.create(AvailabilityDaoImpl.java:51)
    at com.pevco.nexgen.health.handlers.SystemModelListener.onMessage(SystemModelListener.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:622)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:330)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$2.onMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:306)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1321)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 10000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:195)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:65)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:567)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:560)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
    ... 12 more
15:06:06,217 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] DEBUG HikariPool  - Timeout failure  pool HikariPool-0 stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=2)
15:06:06,217 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] WARN  SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
```

(I'll award bounty before time expires, but would like to get the accurate answer.)

Comment: Are you setting the translator to the JdbcTemplate ?

Comment: Yes. I added the Dao code where that takes place. The current code checks for instance of SqlException, but I've also tried it with out any if statement, and it still did not hit the catch clause when the error was a database connection error. I can cause the catch block to be hit by removing a column from a table. So the translator is working for other SqlExceptions just not for database not connected.

Comment: Probably the error is because hakiri os trying to reconnect . And not because of a problem in your template.

Comment: Hikari attempts the reconnection for a specified amount of time, currently set to 1 second. If that times out it throws the database connection error, which the is caught by jdbc template and rethrown as a SqlException. However this exception is not caught by the exception translator. If anyone else is using a translator, I'd like to know how the database connection error is caught and translator.

Comment: In the log I can't see where is the template involve. I think it is not passing by the template. The connection is not asked by the template. It is made by hikari

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the connection is being asked by Hikari component. Probably Hikari lost the connection and it is trying to reconnect.

In the log there is not any part related to the JdbcTemplate. That is because the problem is cause by a reconnection try and not because a new transaction.

If the transaction is not passing by the template the error translator is never called. The event that throws the exception is no fired by the business logic. It is fired by the reconnect or create connection functionality of Hikari

Comment: You are correct in that Hikari did lose the connection because I stopped the database as part of my testing. I see your point that Hikari will try to make the reconnect, but will it do that even if there are no db calls via JdbcTemplate? Hikari is started in the Spring IOC. Is there some way to catch this connection exception and handling it?

Comment: Hikari is a connection pool, so it will create a pool of connections when it starts. When there is a new call, JDBCTemplate ask for a connection to Hikari. And Hikari looks for an available connection in the pool. That's all. That's the way it works. In the other side you have Have Hikari managing the connection pool, it tries to keep a number of open connections, if the number of open connections decrease under the minimum it will try to reconnect that connection, this is automatic, it's started by Hikari not by JDBCTemplate. If you need to catch the exception thrown by Hikari you need ...

Comment: If you need to catch the exception thrown by Hikari you need something like a listener or a class that is aware of the Hikari events. I don't know about Hikari son in this case I couldn't help you with the class or the way it works.

Comment: I wish I could split the bounty since @varad pointed me to the jdbcTemplate code. But everyone else here also made significant comments that caused me to look at the stack trace more closely. The stack trace that is causing the problem is generated by one of my dao's, not even JdbcTemplate. I didn't notice this before since I did not create that dao. Thank-you for the detailed explanation of the connection pool operation. That was the most helpful! I fixed my problem by modifying the oddball dao and logging the error instead of printing stack trace. Daha! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As "reos" pointed out, there is nothing related to JdbcTemplate in the stack trace. That means you tried to open the connection outside the JdbcTemplate.

Even if you used the JdbcTemplate, the exception would not get translated. Look at the [execute method in the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L339). They don't use the custom exception translator if the data source fails to obtain the connection.